# Публикация записи в предложенную новость вк

Tags: javascript, vkontakte-api

группа `https://vk.com/business_card_website` и сайт где выполняется скрипт `http://lsweb.ru/example/post_to_vk_group.php`

Здравствуйте, если выполняю этот код от администратора группы то запись сразу публикуется на стену публичной страницы, а если со страницы подписчика, то запись нигде не публикуется, а должна идти в предложенную новость, как это сделать подскажите?

```
[JS]<script src="http://vkontakte.ru/js/api/openapi.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<div onclick="sendwallpost('Мой текст сообщения');">отправить</div>
<script language="javascript">
    VK.init({
        apiId: 5958669 // id созданного вами приложения вконтакте 
    });

    function sendwallpost(mydata) {
        VK.api("wall.post", {
            owner_id: -115255884,
            signed: 1, 
            from_group: 1,
            message: mydata
        }, function (data) {});
    }
</script>[/JS]
```

Comment: `from_group: 0` попробуйте

Comment: по документации написано если не в администрации то должно попадать в предложенную новость, но все ровно не попадает, а если от админа группы нажимаю кнопку, то сразу на стену, а от обычного пользователя нигде не высвечивается сообщение ни в предлоденной новости ни на стене группы

Comment: Если вы убрали параметр from_group и всё равно не попадает в предложку, значит, дело с token'ом и openapi. С сервера я делал как раз так, со Standalone token'ами пользователей – и всё срабатывало. У вас, я вижу, приложение Standalone, но вы пользуетесь openapi – может, проблема в этом. У вас есть token? Попробуйте напрямую отправлять запросы на api.vk.com/method/wall.post?...